# SonarQube rule squid:S1200 counts java.* classes in its limit of 20?

Tags: java, sonarqube

How does the SonarQube rule

> squid:S1200:  Classes should not be coupled to too many other classes
>   (Single Responsibility Principle)

count the coupling number towards its limit of 20?

It seems like it counts classes from the standard Java packages like `java.lang.*`, `java.text.*` and `java.util.*` in this rule's limit of 20. So If I use the Java `Integer` class, I've used up 1/20 of this rule's limit.

Additional Info:
SonarQube Version: 4.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to answer your question is to look directly at the source code of this rule : 
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/c1f15b81bcd9d643ab403aeea6e1606040f84eac/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/ClassCouplingCheck.java

So it counts every declared type. And so indeed if you use java.lang.Integer it will count as one type so 1/20 of the this rule's limit.

The good news is that you can configure this '20' magical number in your quality profile.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? I didn't see an option to configure this number in our quality profile. Also, according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480655/1093019, it is possible to do it on a per project basis, but I can't find the actual parameter that needs to be set.

Comment: The parameter name for S1200 is "max"