# Modify default parameter rule in SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am using sonarqube to check the quality of my code and I would like to override a rule but I don't manage to do it even by following the documentation. The rule I want to modify is about the exceeding code length in C# which by default uses the **maximumLineLength** parameter. I would like to modify and increase the value of this parameter but I don't find anywhere the chance to do it. Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the attribute in your sonar-project.properties file. That way the default value will stay intact, but it will be set to your desired value per-project...

```
sonar.maximumLineLength = 300 (or whatever value you need)
```

Let us know if it worked.

Comment: How do you determine the parameter name for a particular rule? For example: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1200. I would like to update the current default value of 20.

Comment: the parameter name for S1200 is "max"

Answer (score 2):

Add the following Rule in SonarLint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnalysisInput>
  <Settings>
  </Settings>
  <Rules>
    <Rule>
      <Key>S103</Key>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
          <Key>maximumLineLength</Key>
          <Value>240</Value>
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
    </Rule>
  </Rules>
  <Files>
  </Files>
</AnalysisInput>
```

and Modify the  .csproj file to add the following.

`<ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="Properties\SonarLint.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>`